# How to update a bash script with the old version of this script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a linux bash script, which has a parameter to update the script self. My problem is, that the script can't update itself, while it's used. Well.. Does someone have a solution?

Currently I try to update the script as following:

```
    # Download latest version
    wget -q https://github.com/TS3Tools/TS3UpdateScript/archive/master.zip
    # Unzip latest version
    unzip master.zip TS3UpdateScript-master/* -x TS3UpdateScript-master/configs/ && mv -f TS3UpdateScript-master/* . && rmdir TS3UpdateScript-master/
```

But I receive the following error by the script:

```
    replace TS3UpdateScript-master/LICENSE_GNU_GPL.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
    ateScript-master/configs
    caution: excluded filename not matched:  TS3UpdateScript-master/configs/
    # many arguments
```

I hope, someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What use is the parameter to update script if it can't do so while running?

Comment: Are you the author of said script and you want help fixing the self update, or are you a user and want to make it work? Looking at the script, it seems to have temp file vulnerabilities.

Comment: I'm the author and I want to fix it, but I don't found a solution until yet. The parameter is '--update-script'. Line 267 until 327 of the TS3UpdateScript.sh are for the update process. @Anton What do you mean with "seems to have temp file vulnerabilities"?

Comment: Use gzip instead of zip

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your error comes from file name wildcard without quotes. Bash does globbing first and replaces `*` with lots of filenames and then runs unzip with this parameters. Try `master.zip 'TS3UpdateScript-master/*' -x 'TS3UpdateScript-master/configs/'` .

Then there will be a problem with running a new version of script instead of old one running. I think it should be done like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

version=4
if [ "$UPDATED" != "$0" ]; then
        cp self_update.new.sh self_update.sh
        exec env UPDATED="$0" "$0" "$@"
fi
echo "This script's version is $version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help and ideas! I've "outsourced" the code to another script, which contains following code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    sleep 5s

    # Download latest version
    wget -q https://github.com/TS3Tools/TS3UpdateScript/archive/master.zip
    # Unzip latest version
    if [[ $(unzip master.zip TS3UpdateScript-master/* -x TS3UpdateScript-master/configs/*) ]]; then
            if [ $(cp -Rf TS3UpdateScript-master/* . && rm -rf TS3UpdateScript-master/) ]; then
                    rm -rf master.zip
                    exit 1;
            fi
    else
            rm -rf master.zip
            exit 0;
    fi
```